# Return ArrayList or List?

Tags: java, list, optimization

I'm creating a library to be used by people but why should my method return a **List** instead of an **ArrayList**?

Because if the user knows the real type is an **ArrayList** he will use the accessor [] in a loop instead of iterator but if he doesn't know he will use an iterator.

Same question for **LinkedList**, if the return type is a List he won't be able to use the correct accessor.

Am I right?

Comment: Depends how specific you want to be. Generally, using the `Abstract` parent class is better, it allows people to store the array you're returning in whatever structure implementing `List` they want.

Comment: Always program to the interface when possible.  What did you think the iterator for an arraylist does internally? :)

Comment: Well, I'd most likely use a foreach loop and I can't remember when I last used the direct accessor on an `ArrayList`. If you always iterate over the list anyways you can as well use an iterator.

Comment: How, exactly, do you want to use `[]` on a list? I always access my lists elements with `get(int)`, which works on any list type.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Returning **List** will make it possible for users of your library to use anything that implements a **List** interface, while using an **ArrayList** will force them to use an **ArrayList**.

If in the future, you as a library creator decide to change your internal implementation, that changes will be hidden from the end user by the generic interface to your library.

Comment: Ok but if i have created in my method a List<Obj> l = new ArrayList<Obj>(), the real nature is a ArrayList not a linkedlist so they have to use the accessor and not the iterator ?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't matter, you just specify with the **interface** that it's a `List`, but then the user can choose the **implementation**

Comment: @BaL could you explain what it means that the user can choose the implementation? If the library function returns a List backed by an ArrayList, the user cannot choose to treat it the same as a LinkedList, e.g., the List will not respond to getFirst() or getLast()

Comment: @cyang See my answer for getting round that issue.

Comment: @cyang It just means that the ''appearance'' of the returned structure is a `List`, but what's ''behind'' it can be anything implementing the `List` interface. And yes, of course then you will only be able to use the method declared in the `List` interface, or the user could try to cast the object into any of his favourite implementation, but this might raise some exception.

Comment: @BaL but it seems that whether a `List`, `ArrayList`, or `LinkedList` is returned, the user isn't choosing anything, he or she is just left with whatever the library creator specified.

Comment: @cyang Both parties are a bit more free - it is easy for the end user to convert a List to something more specific (see James Poulson's answer), but a bit harder to do so from one specific implementation to other. Perhaps more importantly, library creator can trivially change the internal implementation without breaking client code. It is a general principle, which is not as apparent with this particular example (because Java provides rich functionality for manipulating lists).

Comment: @ipavlic Thanks, I agree with the latter point, but it is just as easy for a user to change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` and vice-versa as to change from `List` to either (as in James Poulson's answer) since they both implement `Collection` and have copy constructors for `Collection`s (if that's the right terminology).

Comment: @cyang Let's say you have a class for reading from a database. It has a method to return a reader class. That class could read from an Oracle database, MSSQL or something as simple as a text file. It might be returning a `OracleReader`, a `MsSqlReader` or a `FileReader`, and each of them will implement a `countRows()` method. As an end-user you really don't care about the type of the database. Instead of that, the class might return a `DatabaseReader`, and you as an end user could then use `countRows()` on that. If the database changes, your code is still okay.

Comment: @ipavlic I completely agree with you on these points. Back to BaL's original comment, I just don't think that in specifying a function with an interface, you're allowing the user to "choose the implementation." The library creator is the person who chooses the implementation whereas the end user simply has to understand and program to the interface.

Answer (score 8):

Because the users of your library should never know that you are using an ArrayList internally.

For example, say you return an ArrayList and lots of people have started using your library. Now if you suddenly realize a LinkedList better suits your purpose, then you break compatibility for all the folks who are presently using your code.

This is why it is always better to code to an interface, not an implementation, and even more so when you are writing code that is specifically meant to be re-used. The interface (List in this case) acts as a contract between your code and the client's code. It tells them *what* your code does (interface), without telling them *how* it does it (by not exposing the implementation).

Answer (score 5):

Return an interface (or failing that a super class?) if possible. This way the method can have a broader application if overriden. This might prevent some class-specific methods from being available on the returned object but there's nothing stopping a programmer taking the `List` data and copying it to whatever `Collection` they prefer to use.

```
List myList = new MyLibrary().getList();

ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList(myList);
LinkedList myLinkedList = new LinkedList(myList);
```

Comment: Related Javadoc:

[ArrayList constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection))
[LinkedList constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList(java.util.Collection))

Answer (score 1):

Because your user can make from your List either `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, you will leave him a choice. It's called [Programming to Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). You should give users of your API as much freedom as you can and this technique is one of the ways how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have to use an iterator - the List interface supports `get(int index)` as a method. If you want flexibility to change the underlying container to anything supporting the list interface, use `List`. If specific `ArrayList` methods are required on what you return, use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Its the concept of `Interface Polymorphism`.

**2.** Its better to have `List<My_Obj> arr = new ArrayList<My_Obj>;`

**3.** Suppose you want to use **LinkedList instead of ArrayList as somepoint, then you donot
       need to worry abt how to do it..**

Answer (score 1):

If You are returning List then it is possible for users of your library to use anything that implements a List interface. It may be Array List or Linked List.

Answer (score 1):

I typically choose the most general type possible.  In this case, you could return a type that's even more general than a List, such as `Collection` or `Iterable`.

By returning Iterable, the compiler will prevent the calling code from attempting to add elements to your list.  This is much stronger than relying on `Collections.unmodifiableList()` to fail at runtime.

Using more general types also gives you more room to manoeuvre in the future.  Perhaps your method's going to load your data from a streaming source rather than an in-memory source: then Iterable becomes a much more suitable than List.